# Построение слоя Data Access на Entity Framework и классах домена?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, архитектура

Насколько возможно при построении слоя Data Access на базе Entity Framework использовать только доменные классы и EntityTypeConfiguration? 
Или не получится и придётся полностью продублировать их заново, с мелкими отличиями?

И вообще – насколько правилен такой подход?

Сижу вот, делаю наброски разных приложений и пытаюсь понять, как оно будет более правильным при DDD подходе, когда в Domain начинаешь отходить от анемичных моделей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто уже ходил этими дорогами и может подсказать, насколько это перспективный вариант? Обойтись одними и теми же классами – достаточно заманчиво с точки зрения принципы DRY, однако не будет ли правильнее всё-таки продублировать эти же классы заново?

Comment: [Ближайший похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18109547/5752652).

Comment: Вопрос интересный. Стоит отметить, что примерно подобного рода проблема возникает при работе с моделями в случае отображения их на UI: проверка значений вводимых пользователем, в случае WPF реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` и т.п. Таким образом классы модели должны отвечать требованиям для возможности их сохранения в БД, а с другой стороны для верного отображения на UI и контроля вводимых данных пользователем программы.

Comment: У меня всплывает две проблемы при таком подходе: в модель просачивается знание о EF (ненужные int BranID на Product) и проблемы с отсутствием конструктора по умолчанию для linq. Есть подозрение, что только когда модели анемичны (читай: совпадают друг с другом в Domain и DA) – только в этом случае можно один раз их в Domain объявить, а остальное при необходимости сделать в DA через EntityTypeConfiguration)