# Дублирование кода между слоями в 3-ех звенной архитектуре

Tags: c#, .net

Прочитал примеры по реализации 3-ех звенной архитектуры на этом ресурсе:

- [Data Access Layer](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.7.php)
- [Business Logic Layer](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.8.php)
- [Presentation Layer](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.9.php)

В общем, автор приводит примеры и на каждом уровне создает похожие объекты:

На уровне баз данных создаются сущности

На уровне бизнес-логики создаются DTO-объекты

На уровне представления создаются View-модели

Если посмотреть на примеры, то все объекты похожи между собой. Это правильно?

Comment: Это нормально. В реальной жизни и хоть сколько-либо сложном функционале они начнут отличаться и хитро маппиться друг на друга.

Comment: Это нормально. Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/914882/213987