# Передача модели из ajax запроса в экшен

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Есть проблема с передачей данных из ajax запроса в экшен контроллера.

Вот мои модели:

```
public class Mark
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Марка")]
    public string MarkName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Mark()
    {
        CarModels = new List<CarModel>();
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}

public class CarModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Модель")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public int MarkId { get; set; }
    public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public CarModel()
    {
        Equipments = new List<Equipment>();
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}
```

Вот мои частичные представления:

_AddMarkModel:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.CarModel

<div id="AddMarkModel" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Добавление новой марки/модели</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "AddMarkSuccess", OnFailure = "AddMarkError" }))
            {
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("_MarkModel")
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                    <button id="btnConfirm" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Добавить</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_MarkModel:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.CarModel

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, "Марка")
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.RadioButton("Mark", "New", true)
                        <span>Новая</span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "newMark", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.ModelName, "Модель")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.ModelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPass", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.ModelName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    @Html.RadioButton("Mark", "Existing")
                    <span>Существующая</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.Mark.Id, ViewBag.marks as SelectList, new { @id = "exMark", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Из них видно что я использую Html.AjaxBegin.

Который ведёт в экшен:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _AddMarkModel(CarModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
        throw new Exception("Модель не найдена");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        unitOfWOrk.CarModels.Create(model);
        unitOfWOrk.Save();

        return Json(new { result = true });
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("Не все обязательные поля заполнены");
}
```

Но когда я заполняю поля в экшен прилетает только данные по модели машины, а данные по марке машины не прилетают:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя у меня есть другая форма, где используется класс Car точно так же ajax.beginform передаёт данные в контроллер. И там подтягиваются все данные по всем остальным связанным с помощью foreign key моделям. Вот класс car:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Цена")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Количество на складе")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public int? MarkId { get; set; }
    public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

    public int CarModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }

    public int? EquipmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
}
```

Не как не могу понять в чём разница? Подскажите пожалуйста если кто видит в чём проблема. Возможно дело в архитектуре базы данных и entity в случае с car каким то образом догадывается куда какие данные засунуть, а в случае с carmodel нет, но в чём конкретно дело понять не могу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE:

Вот пример моего работающего кода с той проблемой что я описал.

Модели:

```
public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Цена")]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Количество на складе")]
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public int? MarkId { get; set; }
        public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }

        public int? EquipmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public Car()
        {
            Orders = new List<Order>();
        }
    }

public class Mark
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Марка")]
        public string MarkName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public Mark()
        {
            CarModels = new List<CarModel>();
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }

public class CarModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Модель")]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }

        public int MarkId { get; set; }
        public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public CarModel()
        {
            Equipments = new List<Equipment>();
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }

public class Equipment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //Двигателя
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Двигатель")]
        public int Engine { get; set; }
        //Количество лошадиных сил
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Мощность")]
        public int Power { get; set; }
        //Год выпуска
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Год выпуска")]
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        //Тип привода
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Тип привода")]
        public string DriveType { get; set; }
        //КПП
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "КПП")]
        public string Transmission { get; set; }
        //Кузов
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Кузов")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        //Максимальная скорость
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Максимальная скорость")]
        public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
        //Вес
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Вес")]
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        //Бак
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Бак")]
        public int MaxFuelVolume { get; set; }
        //Цвет автомобиля
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Цвет")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        //Изорбражение автомобиля
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Изображение автомобиля")]
        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public Equipment()
        {
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

На форме я выполняю добавление нового автомобиля со всеми характеристиками что тянутся от других моделей.
Моя форма так же как и в прошлом случае составляется из partial view.
Если это имеет значение, моё окно составленное из partial view является модальным и вызывается с помощью jquery.
Вот они:

_AddAuto:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.Car

<div id="AddAuto" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Добавление нового автомобиля</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "AddCarSuccess", OnFailure = "AddCarError" }))
            {
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("_CarAttributes")
                </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button id="btnConfirm" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Добавить</button>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_CarAttributes:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.Car

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    @Html.Label("Автомобиль:")
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Price, "Цена")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPrice", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Count, "Количество на складе")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Count, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtCount", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Count, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, "Марка")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMarkName", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, "Модель")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtModelName", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <br />
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Picture, "Изображение Автомобиля", new { @style = "padding-right: 50px" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Picture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "hidden", @id = "image" } })
                        <br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Picture, "", new { @id = "pictureError", @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="fileLoader" type="file" accept="image/*" />
                        <img id="autoPicture" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    @Html.Label("Комплектация:")
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Engine, "Двигатель")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Engine, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtEngine", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Engine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Power, "Мощность")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Power, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPower", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Power, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.ReleaseYear, "Год выпуска")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.ReleaseYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtYear", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.ReleaseYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.DriveType, "Тип привода")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.DriveType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtDriveType", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.DriveType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Transmission, "КПП")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Transmission, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtTransmission", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Transmission, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Body, "Кузов")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtBody", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxSpeed, "Максимальная скорость")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxSpeed, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMaxSpeed", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxSpeed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Weight, "Вес")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Weight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtWeight", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Weight, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxFuelVolume, "Бак")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxFuelVolume, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtFuel", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.MaxFuelVolume, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Color, "Цвет")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Color, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtColor", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Color, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заметьте, что но на partialview _CarAttributes я для того что бы у меня все данные собрались в модель через модель Car лезу в другие модели в EditorFor, например `@Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Weight`

И вот мой контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _AddAuto(Car car)
        {
            if (car == null)
                throw new Exception("Автомобиль не найден");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                unitOfWOrk.Cars.Create(car);
                unitOfWOrk.Save();

                return PartialView("_Car", car);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Не все обязательные поля заполнены");
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на скриншоте заполнены все данные не только по модели Car но и по всем остальным, тот же Вес который я привёл для примера ранее. Если посмотрите на View всё увидите.

И вот что мне прилетает в контроллер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание что хоть я и использую на вход модель Car но прилетают и все остальные модели. На последнем скриншоте я привёл пример только что помимо модели Car мне в контроллер пришла ещё и модель Equipment но там ещё пришли 2 модели, Mark и CarModel. Вот пример того что это работает.

Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вот за другую форму ничего сказать не могу, а вот на этой у меня сразу же вопрос: если на классе у вас поле MarkId -- то почему во вью вы указываете не его, а Mark.Id?

Comment: @AK тут я в дроп даун лист собираю все марки. Я просто лезу через foreign key из класса carmodel в класс mark. Если вы об этом.

Comment: @AK я даже ради интереса попробовал создать viewmodel куда запихнул и CarModel и Mark. Добавил в обе вью эту viewmodel в качестве входной модели. И так же к полям привязал нужные мне поля из моделей. И в итоге даже не ввожу значений, нажимаю кнопку добавить. Код залазиет в экшен. И там я просто в шоке. Экземпляр моей viewmodel'и создался. С пустым CarModel, и Mark = null. То есть даже при учёте что я данных вообще не подавал, CarModel создалось, а Mark нет. Не могу понять вообще в чём дело. Мистика какая то)

Comment: @AK взгляните пожалуйста на новый текст вопроса. Я там всё подробно расписал как у меня это работает на другой странице.

Comment: @AK если можно создайте чат там бы это обсудить было лучше, если у вас конечно есть время.

Comment: Не хочу создавать новый, пишите в [шарповский чатик](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--). Но вообще - в чате неудобно будет читать код, а ведь вы так с момента первого комментария никак не приведёте пример некоей другой формы. Это лучше сделать в вопросе, а не в чате.

Comment: @AK я уже заменил вопрос.

Comment: @AK там моя форма на которой это работает. Вы можете уже прочитать код тут, а в теме обсудим.

Comment: @AK возможно уже нечего моделировать не нужно, может я чего то не понимаю но это какая то мистика. У меня на форме там есть 2 Radiobutton'а, я думаю вы их заметили. И в первом который как раз перед полем для ввода новой марки, есть признак checked: true. `@Html.RadioButton("Mark", "New", true)` Так вот стоит его убрать. И в прилитевшей модели сразу же появляется Mark. Скрин в вопросе.

Comment: @AK и даже если яв процессе работы с формой сам чекну любой радиобаттон, всё данные не летят. Если не чекать то всё нормально долетает.

Comment: @AK стоило назвать DropDown отлично от названия модели, например `@Html.RadioButton("Check", "New")` и всё нормально, при чекнутом радиобаттоне всё нормально работает. Спасибо. Приму ваш ответ. Свой стоит написать для шпаргалки на будущее? Ну по поводу названия радиобаттона?

Comment: Напишите лучше свой ответ и поставьте туда галку. Вы например нашли, при каких условиях начинает работать - но ведь нужно же и объяснить почему заработало. В моём ответе этого нет.

Comment: @AK кстати если будет время вечером не забудьте пожалуйста о том что я в чате просил примерчик по поводу viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что у радиобаттона было такое же название как и у модели, `Mark`

```
@Html.RadioButton("Mark", "NewMark", true)
```

И это блокировало передачу модели в контроллер.

Answer (score 2):

У вас на классе CarModel  указан MarkId, вот его и указывайте, а не Mark.Id раз вы пишете `@model CarModel`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код собрал из предоставленных вами классов, просто повырезал не относящееся к делу:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.CarModel

@{
    var data = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" },
    };  
}

<div class="container">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.MarkId, data)
</div>
```

и убрав ajax:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_AddMarkModel", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Далее. Если вас интересует, чтобы некоторый паршиал _partial123 вводил модель Mark

```
@Html.Partial("_partial123", new Mark(...))
```

то и пишите так, но первой строкой в _partial123 должно стоять @model Mark

Если предположить, что вы в _MarkModel хотите указать параметры для Mark - ну так и напишите @model Mark - но у вас же там снова стоит @model CarModel.

Но вообще, давайте прямо. У вас нужно ввести совершенно простую модель:

```
public class CarModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public int MarkId { get; set; }
}
```

Это совершенно примитивнейшая модель. Я вижу, что у вас есть некоторые куски кода, которые позволяют не выбирать MarkId из существующего dropdown, а создать новый -- но если этого нет, то у вас абсолютно тривиальная модель из id, строкового поля и одного dropdown (см. мой код выше, там убрано всё лишнее).

Он абсолютно твириальный, там НЕТ НИКАКОЙ необходимости вводить Mark.
При сохранении Id,ModelName, MarkId сохранится без проблем.

А вот если вы хотите сделать создание Mark на лету - вам нужно всего-навсего добавить ещё одну строку к модели:

```
public class CarModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public int MarkId { get; set; }

    public int NewMarkName  { get; set; }
}
```

И контроллер будет лишь чуть сложнее:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _AddMarkModel(CarModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
        throw new Exception("Модель не найдена");

    var car = new Car
    {
        ModelName = model.ModelName,
        MarkId = model.MarkId,
    };

    if (model.MarkId == 0)
    {
        var mark = new Mark{MarkName = model.NewModelName};
        this.Db.Marks.Add(mark);
        this.Db.SaveChanges();
        car.MarkId = mark.Id;
    }

    this.Db.Cars.Add(car);
    this.Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Поэтому в selectlist нужно добавить ещё одно значение, с нулём - для добавления нового значения. Я это сделаю так:

```
    var data = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "выберите чтобы создать новую модель", Value = "0" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Bentley", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Crysler", Value = "2" },
    };
```

А вы воспользуйтесь перегрузкой у dropdown есть одна, где можно дополнительно добавить options.

И *только когда поймёте эту систему* -- только тогда и наворачивайте дополнительный переключатель создать новую марку/выбрать существующую (причём это вам даже не нужно делать полем модели CarModel - так и будете ориентироваться на MarkId = 0 чтобы создать модель). Просто будете в js дизаблить пункты на клиенте: если новая - то дизаблить дропдаун, если существующая - то поле с маркой скрывать.
Но на модели это поле избыточно. Его не нужно передавать. Несмотря на наличие валидации на клиенте бекенд никогда не должен ей доверять (случаи поломанных скриптов, хакерские атаки и т.п.)

Эта система абсолютно проста и надёжна как автомат Калашникова. И только если у вас когда-нибудь попадётся сайт, где при создании машины можно будет указать сложный класс (Mark будет состоять не из одной строки, а из двух или пятнидцати) -- тогда и можно будет пойти совсем другим путём:

```
public class CarModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public int MarkId { get; set; }

    public Mark NewMark  { get; set; }
}
```

И вот только тогда у вас будет подключаться паршиал вот так:

@Html.Partial("_partial123", new Mark(...))

и в _partial123 будет стоять как @model Mark и вот только тогда у вас внутри этого паршиала будет НУЖНО писать `@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.Id` и у вас оно прилетит как NewMark.Id

Но и в этом случае в контроллере вы будете проверять MarkId == 0 и если ноль, то создавать новый Mark из пришедших данных.

Но обратите внимание: в модели CarModel НЕЛЬЗЯ будет указывать `public Mark Mark  { get; set; }` и поле NewMark НЕЛЬЗЯ будет показывать EF'у, у вас CarModel будет вьюмоделью, EF вообще ничего не будет знать о такой сущности, вы будете только с Car и Mark работать.

И вы эту разницу сейчас не понимаете - между моделью, которая нужна только для ввода (и её не сохраняют в базу) и моделью для EF.

У вас если будет слоистая структура приложения, то в проекте БД EF будет знать только о классах Car и Mark. А класс CarViewModel будет находиться application слое и дальше контроллера он вообще никуда не пойдёт. (Когда вам не понравятся распухшие от логики контроллеры ("[контроллеры должны быть тонкими](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/923666/213987)") - это можно будет поправить, но всё равно вы будете в application слое разбиать CarViewModel на отдельные кусочки и сохранять в базу только Car и/или Mark)

PS Есть ещё вариант: вы можете вообще удалить класс Car(View)Model из проекта. И работать только с Car и только с Mark:

```
public JsonResult Asdfgh(Car car, Mark newMark)
```

Но и в этом случае вы будете работать с newMark только в случае если MarkId у car будет равен 0.

Comment: AK я попробовал как вы сказали вместо Mark.Id для дроп даун листа написать MarkId. С дроп даун листом всё нормально. Туда подтягиваются все значения как и раньше. Но в экшен всё так же не приходят данные по модели Mark правда не пробовал пока что убрать ajax запрос, сейчас попробу, но что то у меня подазрение что нечего не изменится.

Comment: @Андрей Во-первых, вы говорили, что у вас не подтягивается марка, но  марка однозначно определяется MarkId - видимо вам нужно было чётко обозначить, что у вас подтягивается dropdown (не верю, на окне дебага у вас его вообще нет) и не подтягивается Mark. Выбор марки - это достаточно выбрать только id, потому что при сохранении в базу по этому ключу подтянется и всё остальное. А во-вторых, как вы не видите, что у вас невозможно подтягивание марки? То есть вы ожидаете что в частичном представлении придёт Mark, но пишете не `@model Mark`, а `@model CarModel`, понимаете это?

Comment: понял что вы имеете в виду. У меня просто на форме либо выбирается существующая марка из выпадающего списка, либо вписывается новая. Скрин в вопросе.

Comment: AK, да вы правильно поняли, я хочу что бы подтянулись данные о Mark. Так как у меня есть другая форма на которой входной моделью является Car. Но там подтягиваются ещё 3 модели. Если нужно могу привести пример кода той страницы.

Comment: Почему на моём скрине нет id Mark потому что я пробовал с вводом новой марки а не с выбором новой из списка.

Comment: AK я понял как вы предлагаете сделать. Но просто почему я цепляюсь за свой вариант, так это потому что на другой форме у меня это работает. Я сейчас В вопросе заменю код на то же самое с другой моделью только работающий.