# Валидация модели при отправке ajax запроса

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть сайт на asp.net mvc.
Есть страничка с добовлением 2 полей. Первое поле может быть либо вписано в EditorFor, либо выбрано из выпадающего списка, а второе обязательно вписано новое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если например задизейблен dropdownlist.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.Mark.Id, ViewBag.marks as SelectList, new { @id = "exMark", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled"* })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Mark.MarkName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Тогда в ModelState на сервере 2 поля для валидирования, оба EditorFor как и должно быть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тогда если я заполню их то валидация пройдёт.

Но если у меня будет задизейблен EditorFor и будет выбираться первое поле из выпадающего списка и в таком случае предпологается что не должно восприниматься значение в EditorFor для первого поля. Тогда почему то на сервере в ModelState все 3 поля используются для валидации и получается если я даже введу оба поля а задизейбленый EditorFor соответсвенно останется пустым, валидация не пройдёт так как оно тоже берётся во внимание. Почему так происходит? Дизейбл не работает для EditorFor в части валидации модели.

Вот скрин если задизейблено поле для ввода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть дело?

Comment: прикрепите пример Вашего EditorFor кода для лучше понимания, что у Вас происходит в обоих случаях

Comment: Я так понимаю, ругается на поле ModelName при задизабленном дропдауне? [Оно же у вас required](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/937404/213987) - если вы дизеблите это поле, то на бекенде его нет и при валидации получаете "нет обязательного поля".

Comment: @AK вы правы, DropDown же у меня ссылается на `i => i.Mark.Id` а EditorFor на `i => i.Mark.MarkName`. А как так можно сделать что бы учитывать либо то либо то? Или для этого не подойдёт валидация на сервере?

Comment: Придётся свою писать на js?

Comment: Ну либо сделать поле необязательным и писать кастомную валидацию (то проверять поле, то нет - в зависимости от переключателя), либо идти по тем альтернативным вариантам, что я [описывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/937404/213987) в прошлом вашем вопросе. Писать ответ не буду - сами потом укажите, на каком варианте остановились.

Comment: @AK хорошо, подумаю как лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбран вариант отмены обязательности заполнения полей на сервере и валидация на клиенте.

```
function BeforeSave() {
        var ddlMark = $('#ddlExMark').val();
        var ddlModel = $('#ddlExModel').val();

        if ((!ddlMark || ddlMark === '') || (!ddlModel || ddlModel === '')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю на сколько правильный метод я использую. Изучаю asp-net меньше месяца и столкнулся с почти аналогичной проблемой.
Если мне надо исключить свойство из проверки на валидацию, то использую следующее:

```
var modelPropertyExclude = nameof(Class.PropertyA);
if (ModelState[modelPropertyExclude].Errors.SingleOrDefault() != null)
{
    ModelState[modelPropertyExclude].Errors.Clear();
}
```

где `modelPropertyExclude` свойство, которое необходимо исключить.

Набросал простой пример. Пусть у нас есть такие модели:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Info Info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.UserEntity

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Registration Page";
}


<form method="post">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Info.Id)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Info.Id)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Info.Id)
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

И контроллер:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserEntity userEntity)
    {
        var modelPropAsString = "Info.Id";

        if (ModelState[modelPropAsString].Errors.SingleOrDefault() != null)
        {
            ModelState[modelPropAsString].Errors.Clear();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("About");
        else
            return View(userEntity);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Если поле Id оставить пустым, то все равно `ModelState.IsValid = true`

Comment: Emigran попробовал ваш способ `var modelProp = nameof(Mark.MarkName);

            if (ModelState[modelProp].Errors.SingleOrDefault() != null)
                ModelState[modelProp].Errors.Clear();`, вылетает ошибка `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.` так как `ModelState[modelProp] null`.

Comment: Попробуйте без nameof тогда. modelProp = “Mark.MarkName”

Comment: @Андрей добавил пример

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример. Да свойства из проверки исключились, но при попытки сохранить мою модель я получил ошибку. `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.` Погуглил в чём может быть дело. Нашёл что можно поместить в try, catch и найти причину ошибки. Мне выдало 2 ошибки. CarModel с состоянием added, и Mark с тем же состоянием, так что хоть я и исключил их из проверки но всё равно сохранить не даёт.

Comment: Возможно Mark.Id = null, когда свойство из проверки исключили и поэтому не сохраняет в БД?

Comment: Нет Mark.Id и CarModel.Id значения остались