# Скрыть элементы в выпадающем списке

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enum

Есть выпадающий список и перечисление. Специально для этого вопроса я взял пример из открытых источников.
Как из выпадающего списка который заполнен элементами из enum убрать(скрыть) 1 или несколько элементов которые меня не устраивают, но при этом не трогать само перечилсение enum? Ну например не нравится мне утро и день. Хочу только чтобы выводилось вечер и ночь.
Вот код и пример.

```
    public enum DayTime
    {
        [Display(Name = "Утро")]
        Morning,
        [Display(Name = "День")]
        Afternoon,
        [Display(Name = "Вечер")]
        Evening,
        [Display(Name = "Ночь")]
        Night
    }

    public class DayTimeViewModel
    {
        public DayTime Period { get; set; }
    }

@model DayTimeViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}   

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Period">Время суток</label>
            <select asp-for="Period" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DayTime>()"></select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Я бы попробовал в эту сторону подумать: [привести к IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909671/5752652) `Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayTime)).Cast<DayTime>()`, там отобрать нужные значения `.Where(x => x == DayTime.Morning || x == DayTime.Afternoon)` и построить нужную модель `.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() } )` и строил бы не GetEnumSelectList а типовой DropDown (что-то типа как тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/937418/213987 ). Проекта под рукой нет попробовать, просто концепт. Ещё непонятно вот что: русификация слетит?