# ASP.NET MVC C#. Как убрать множество параметров в конструкторе контроллера?

Tags: c#, ооп, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, repository

Темка значит следующая. Изучаю я значит Asp.net mvc и думаю...

Есть универсальный BaseRepository. В нем представлены универсальные методы, применимые ко всем моделям бд.

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IModel, new()
{
    protected readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;
    public BaseRepository()
    {
    }
    public BaseRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }
}
```

Есть просто Repository, которые наследуется от BaseRepository. В нем представлены уникальные методы для конкретной модели бд. В данном случае - для модели Vacancy

```
public class VacancyRepository : BaseRepository<Vacancy>
{
    public VacancyRepository()
    {
    }
    public VacancyRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext) : base(appDbContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Есть RepositoriesUnitOfWork, где создаются репозитории.

```
public class RepositoriesUnitOfWork
{
    private AppDbContext _appDbContext { get; set; }

    private VacancyRepository vacancy;

    public VacancyRepository Vacancy
    {
        get
        {
            if (vacancy == null)
                vacancy = new VacancyRepository(_appDbContext);
            return vacancy;
        }
    }

    public RepositoriesUnitOfWork(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }
}
```

Далее в Startup'e подключается RepositoriesUnitOfWork

```
services.AddTransient<RepositoriesUnitOfWork>();
```

Далее этот RepositoriesUnitOfWork можно юзать в сервисах и контроллерах, все прекрасно... Пока сервисов и репозиториев мало. При большом их количестве получается вот такая вот не приятная картина в конструкторе контроллера

```
public VacancyController(RepositoriesUnitOfWork repositoriesUnitOfWork,
        VacancyService vacancyService, BookService bookService,
        CatService catService)
```

Передаем RepositoriesUnitOfWork для использования простых запросов к бд, без дублирования кода в сервисе. Ну и сервисы, которые используются в контроллере.

Это. Не. Красиво.

И ведь это не самый жирный контроллер, есть примеры пострашней.

Что же делать?

Очевидно проблема в архитектуре, но другой я пока не знаю... вот я и решил самостоятельно что-нибудь придумать.

А что если сделать вот так?

```
public class DbModel<T, Repos, Serv> : BaseRepository<T> 
    where T : class
    where Repos : class, IRepository<T>, new()
    where Serv : class, IService<T>, new()
{

    private Repos repository;
    public Repos Repository
    {
        get
        {
            if (repository == null)
                repository = new Repos()
                {
                    Base = base.GetThis()
                };
            return repository;
        }
    }

    private Serv service;
    public Serv Service
    {
        get
        {
            if (service == null)
                service = new Serv()
                {
                    Base = base.GetThis()
                };
            return service;
        }
    }
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : DbSet<T> where T : class
{
    protected BaseRepository<T> GetThis()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class BookRepository : IRepository<Book>
{
    public BaseRepository<Book> Base { get; set; }

    public void GetR()
    {

    }
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public BaseRepository<T> Base { get; set; }
}

public class BookService : IService<Book>
{
    public BaseRepository<Book> Base { get; set; }

    public void GetS()
    {

    }
}

public interface IService<T> where T: class
{
    public BaseRepository<T> Base { get; set; }
}
```

А потом в AppDbContext поменять DbSet на подобное

```
DbModel<Book, BookRepository, BookService> Books { get; set; }
```

Вкидываем туда тип модели бд, репозиторий и сервис.

Теперь можно использовать один класс (AppDbContext) как модель (не бд, а буковка M из MVC)

В конструктор идет только один объект из которого очень удобно можно достать нужные методы.

Кроме того, из-за того что BaseRepository наследован от DbSet можно переопределять методы DbSet как только вздумается. Удобно.

Вопрос следующий.

- Насколько "правильно" использовать подобную архитектуру?
- Не нарушает ли это ООП?
- Есть ли более "правильные" способы убрать миллион параметров в конструкторе контроллера?

Comment: Очень похоже на generic repository, который нынче считается антипаттерном. Альтернатива - Mediatr, я писал несколько раз про него в ответах ([sample1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/923666/213987), а также делал проект на github'е: https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend

Comment: Спасибо, интересно, почитаю.

Comment: Большое число зависимостей в конструкторе (over-injection) может быть признаком нарушения принципа единственной обязанности (SRP в SOLID), т.е. может быть стоит просто разбить "жирный" контроллер на несколько.