# Как правильно спрятать ORM?

Tags: c#, архитектура, orm

Допустим есть БД и взаимодействие с ней выполняется через какое-то ORM.

Собственно, вопрос в том, как правильно скрыть ее от внешнего мира, НО не во вред юзабилити и чтобы в любой момент ее можно было легко сменить на другую?

Я вижу решение в виде какого-то сервиса у которого дергается какой-то метод и тот возвращает какой-то результат. Однако, проблема такого подхода в том, что в конечном итоге может наплодится много методов вида `GetBy*`, хотя если работать с ORM напрямую, то можно в `LINQ` стиле все фильтровать на ходу без создания доп. методов.

Еще одно решение-это наружу выставить `Enumerable`, но в таком случае, если я не ошибаюсь, то данные будут целиком все материализоваться, что не есть хорошо, но будет гибкость сравнимая с прямым взаимодействием через ORM...

Comment: Спрятать любой архитектурный слой можно создав на границе набор Dto и всё, никто не знает о классах за границей. Только за любой слой нужно платить ([тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/914882/213987)). Вы готовы платить за абстрагирование от ОРМ созданием всех классов в двойном экземпляре? И, не совсем понятно, почему вы думаете, что сможете избежать материализации данных: вы так расплывчато описали вопрос (сервис между приложениями? между слоями приложения?) что можно сказать "вообще-то рано или поздно вам придётся материализовать данные".

Comment: Под материализацией во втором примере я имею ввиду в свойство =>context.Entity.Select(x=>x). Т.е всю сущность материализовывать.

Comment: А куда вы это выставляете? В своё же приложение в другой слой или "наружу" во "внешний мир", в WCF/WebApi сервис, о которых вы говорите в последних вопросах?

Comment: В другой слой..

Comment: Тогда я согласен, что это холиварный вопрос и очень сильно зависящий от задач -- и мы уже толи тут, толи на хабре это обсуждали, что и IEnumerable бывает хорошо и IQuerable. Давайте минус эту часть вопроса, чтобы не уходить в любимые цвета фломастеров (лично я считаю, что нужно фигачить IEnumerable -- и если мне вдруг хочется "эх, а хорошо было бы здесь ещё отфильтровать" - то я сразу иду пересматривать исходный запрос)

Comment: На счет DTO. Ну тогда полу, что слой работы с БД- это что-то типа класса-сервиса => нужно городить мноество методов Get*...

Comment: А вы как хотели? Альтернатива -- выставить четыре CRUD метода (паттерн Generic Repository), вы же понимаете или самому не нравится? Давайте определимся, что мы хотим: размазывать по всему коду приложения Get* методы зная о базе, либо волевой рукой зажать детали реализации в слое бд, абстрагировавшись за интерфейсами и Dt-классами. Я кажется, понимаю, что хочется взять плюсы обоих методов и не заплатить за минусы каждого. Но (см. выше) так не бывает: либо абстракции протекают, либо мы ставим архитектурную границу и платим за неё.

Comment: Даю финальный ответ на ваш вопрос: я для себя после нескольких лет работы с EF и Dapper понял, что полная абстракция от ОРМ -- вещь о которой я мечтал, но ни разу мне не пригодилось менять, а главное -- стоимость этой абстракции такая высокая, что я решил забить на это. (При этом что, ну я всё-таки стараюсь придерживаться архитектурных границ, если это не сильно накладно. [Текущий вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/923732/213987): [MediatR + CQRS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lwCVE_XgqI&index=7&list=LLFAXGDZ1WrEdqvPUmNRPQcA&t=0s)) Всё, больше мне нечего сказать по этому вопросу.