# Показ страниц пагинации

Tags: c#, алгоритм, asp.net-core, linq, пагинация

[Есть у меня код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/951800/213987), который выводит пагинацию на странице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это выводятся все элементы как есть - от первого до MaxPage:

```
@if (Model.IsFirst())
{
    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="@Model.GetUrl(1)"><<</a></li>
    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="@Model.GetUrl(Model.PageNumber - 1)"><</a></li>
}
else
{
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="@Model.GetUrl(1)"><<</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="@Model.GetUrl(Model.PageNumber - 1)"><</a></li>
}

@for (var i = 1; i <= Model.MaxPageCount; i++)
{
    if (Model.IsCurrent(i))
    {
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link disabled" href="@Model.GetUrl(i)">@i</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="@Model.GetUrl(i)">@i</a>
        </li>
    }
}
```

Проблемы начинаются, когда число страниц становится больше 10 (а частенько в пагинации и по триста страниц бывает) - они улетают за правую границу экрана.

Сижу думаю, какое условие нужно взять чтобы пагинация показывалась красиво.

Попробуем формализовать условие. Есть некоторая `IEnumerable<int>` от 1 до Model.MaxPageCount и есть некоторое число PageNumber (текущий номер страницы) которое принадлежит этой последовательности.

Не уверен точно, но допустим мне надо получить не более пяти элементов ДО текущей страницы и не более пяти элементов ПОСЛЕ текущей страницы.

При этом я не знаю, как красиво обработать ситуацию, что если страниц ДО не хватает (допустим, мы смотрим страницу 3, тогда ДО будут страницы 1 и 2) то после наверное стоит взять чуть больше - не пять, а на на три больше. Но и не факт, что ПОСЛЕ хватит нужного числа страниц.

Вопрос скорее на красивый и простой алгоритм (как это принято делать в типичных пагинаторах?), возможно что конкретную формулу я и сам напишу. Если кто сталивался с подобной задачей и знает, как такое можно сделать - предложите вариант. Я смотрел разные варианты XPagedList на github, но какого-то удобного варианта не нашёл.

Comment: Вот здесь посмотрите ф-ю `RecalcList`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP ого, вот это ответ так ответище. Сразу по Кролю заскучал от такого ответа )

Comment: @tym32167, ага и пагинация там вполне достойная

Comment: Отличный ответ, а самое интересное, что на нём есть мой апвоут, значит, когда-то я его уже видел )) Сделал по аналогии.

Answer (score 1):

Что то типа такого?

```
List<int> GeneratePages(int currentPage, int totalPages)
{
    var pages = new List<int>();
    for(var i=currentPage; i>0 && i>=currentPage-5; i--) pages.Add(i);
    pages.Reverse();    
    for(var i=currentPage+1; i<=totalPages && i<=currentPage+5; i++) pages.Add(i);
    return pages;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(50, 100)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(1, 100)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(2, 100)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(98, 100)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(99, 100)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(100, 100)));
```

Результаты

```
45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
94,95,96,97,98,99,100
95,96,97,98,99,100
```

---

Если, например, хочется видеть в сумме 11 элементов (то есть в идеале 5 слева, 5 спава, 1 текущий) и адаптировать при сдвигах (2 слева, 1 текущий, 8 справа - для страницы номер 3), то ваот второй вариант

```
List<int> GeneratePages(int currentPage, int totalPages, int expectedpages)
{
    var beforeCurrent = new Stack<int>();
    var afterCurrent = new Queue<int>();
    var expected = expectedpages - 1;
    var i = currentPage-1;
    var j = currentPage+1;

    while(expected > 0)
    {
        var local = expected;

        if (i > 0) {
            beforeCurrent.Push(i);
            i--;
            expected--;
        }

        if (j<=totalPages && expected > 0)
        {
            afterCurrent.Enqueue(j);
            j++;
            expected--;
        }

        if (local == expected) break;
    }

    var res = new List<int>();
    while(beforeCurrent.Count>0) res.Add(beforeCurrent.Pop());
    res.Add(currentPage);
    while(afterCurrent.Count>0) res.Add(afterCurrent.Dequeue());
    return res;
}
```

Проверяем

```
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(50, 100, 11)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(1, 100, 11)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(2, 100, 11)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(98, 100, 11)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(99, 100, 11)));
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(100, 100, 11)));  
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", GeneratePages(2, 5, 11)));
```

Вывод

```
45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, натолкнуло на некоторые мысли. В итоге правда сделал по ответу Влада, очень уж там всё красиво было.

Comment: @AK но проблем :)

Answer (score 1):

Сделано [по ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/218063) @VladD:

```
void Main()
{
    var lastPage = 20;
    var currentPage = 3;

    var result = this.GetPaging(currentPage, lastPage);

    result.Dump();
}

IEnumerable<int> GetPaging(int currentPage, int lastPage)
{
    var maxBefore = 5;
    var maxAfter = 5;

    var first = currentPage - maxBefore;

    if(first < 1)
        first = 1;

    var last = currentPage + maxAfter;

    if(last > lastPage)
        last = lastPage;

    return Enumerable.Range(first, last - first);
}
```