# Использование библиотеки DataAnnotations для валидации данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, аннотации, codefirst

Начал изучать разделение приложения по слоям. Onion архитектура с метанита.
Всё вроде бы работает. Начал валидировать страницу регистрации.
Добавляю в модель client обязательность полей:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CSurname { get; set; }
    public string CName { get; set; }
    public string CPatronymic { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
}
```

Добавляю миграцию, а реакции 0. При таком же использовании этой библиотики в обычном приложении mvc, там у меня всё в одном проекте. Создаётся not null у поля на котором эта аннотация. А тут этого не происходит. И соответственно не вылетает ошибка когда я оставляю поле пустым. Вот небольшие куски моего кода. Если понадобиться что то ещё напишите. Я покажу весь необходимый код:
View:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-signin">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\AutoStore\AutoStore\App_Data\AutoDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Вроде бы всё привёл что может понадобиться. Получается что модель у меня находиться в домен коре. Контекст в infrastructure.data а view регистрации в основном проекте. Все в разных. Я вот думаю что тут в этом дело, но понять в чём конкретно не могу.

Comment: На вид выглядит всё правильно и должно отрабатывать. (Есть некоторые случаи, когда Required не применяется - в TPH для производных типов, но это не ваш случай, у вас просто строка). Приведено много лишнего, достаточно первого класса. У вас `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` в первом классе есть, всё так? PS Уверен, что вопрос "вызыван опечаткой", какой-то банальной. Скажем, не сделали Update-Database или сделали на другой сервер )

Comment: @AK проблема оказывается не в аннотации. Я попробовал добавить новое свойство в этом классе, написал add-migration ... и миграция пустая. Почему то не видит обновлений. У меня есть предположение что в прошлый раз когда я делал миграцию создавая всю базу, у меня был ninject а теперь я его удалил, так как использую unitofwork принцип и подумал что не нужен, это ведь может быть из за нинжекта? Потому что получается как я описал выше что классы в одном проекте, контекст в другом, а веб конфиг вообще в третьем. То есть сё по разным классам, как то же этому всему связываться нужно?

Comment: Ну я так и думал, что проблема вызвана чем-то иным, потому что всё правильно описано. И разделение классов по нескольким проектам - вообще [не помеха](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/766614/213987).

Comment: @AK то есть дело в ninject ? Нужно сделать его так как описано на metanit?

Comment: @AK нашёл свою глупую ошибку. Когда я начал создавать проект, перед тем как разнести всё по слоям я создал в основном проекте свои модели в папке Models и класс context и оттуда всё и тянулось, а на мои модели в домене даже не смотрело. Сейчас я удалил модели в основном проекте. Добавил ninject как и описано на metanit, но теперь проблема при включении миграций в проекте. Мой проект не видит контекста. Вот ошибка `No context type was found in the assembly 'AutoStore'.` И теперь я не понимаю как мне связать мой основной проект с тем где находится контекст?

Comment: @AK и эту проблему решил. Просто нужно писать enable-migrations с казанием -ProjectName и название проекта где находиться класс контекста. И даже ninject вообще не нужен, всё и так работает. Только вот интересный такой момент остался. В модели у меня называется допустим класс Car и в контексте dbset тоже car а название таблицы создаётся cars. От чего это зависит? Не подскажите?

Comment: Ну... видимо вы просто не освоились с механизмами миграции, поэтому и ошибки такие. Указание проекта можно делать и из [выпадающего списка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORN9U.png). Предлагаю закрыть вопрос как "вызван опечаткой или не воспроизводится". Или напишите ответ сами, глядишь кому пригодится

Comment: @AK понял, нашёл выпадающий список. Ну как я понял ninject всё же не нужен для того что бы это всё работало. А вы не подскажите всё же что отвечат за то какие будут названия у таблиц? Просто у меня класс есть Car, а таблица называется Cars. Почему так?

Comment: Потому что EF основан на такой вещи как конвенции. Например, Id - это автоматом первичный ключ и можно не писать [PrimaryKey] на нём. А та конвенция про которую вы говорите - это "плюрализация имён таблиц", её можно [отключить](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4425027/5752652). В EF вшиты правила английского языка для плюрализации (когда добавлять -s, когда -es и даже исключения). В EF 6 эта конвенция по умолчанию, в EF Core вроде убрали.

Comment: @AK а поподробнее можно? А с вопросом я завтра разберусь, последую одному из ваших советов.

Comment: @AK и ещё я открыл вопрос с похожей тематикой, не посмотрите если вам не сложно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927818/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-dataannotation

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том что я запускал команды миграции не из того проекта где у меня находиться класс conext. А как только начал запускать из нужного проекта всё заработало.