# Валидация модели с помощью dataannotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, валидация

Пытаюсь повесить на модель валидацию. Вот моя модель:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CSurname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CPatronymic { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
}
```

Все поля в ней обязательны. При регистрации специально не ввожу например фамилию. Но сообщения об ошибке не следует на view. Вот код:

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-signin">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Хотя когда смотришь в отладке. Условие false. Лезу внутрь ModelState нахожу там error и его текст, но почему то на view он не выводиться. В чём может быть дело?

Вот весь код view:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.Client

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .form-signin {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 330px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .input-group-text {
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    }

    .form-control {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
</style>

@Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index")

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CName, "Имя")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите имя" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "Отчество")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CPatronymic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPatr", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите отчество" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Login, "Логин")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Login, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtLogin", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите логин" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Password, "Пароль")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(i => i.Password, new { @id = "txtPass", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите пароль" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Email, "E-Mail")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMail", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите e-mail", @type = "email" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Добавить" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

А вот пример ошибки если в поле email нет @:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при ajax запросе такого не происходит.

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если сделать отправку формы не ajax а с помощью beginform тогда валидация отрабатывает. Почему так? Или я что то должен ещё в success или error указать что бы всё отработало?

Comment: А вы знаете, что это за [параметр](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ee703502%28v%3dvs.100%29), который вы в null проставили? Если поставить `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CSurname)` ошибка выводится?

Comment: @AK если не ошибаюсь это validation message. Но у меня в таком варианте всё выводиться при обычной отправке формы с помощью post запроса. Там выводиться дефолтное сообщение. А при ajax запросе нет.

Comment: @AK я попробовал вместо пустоты написать туда сообщение во второй параметр, но тогда он пишеться сразу после загрузки формы. в момент когда jquery подписываться на #btn. И это сообщение весит всегда, но это не то.

Comment: @Ak проверил ещё кое что. У меня на странице например есть поле с типом email и оно должно возвращать своё сообщение если в поле нет @. И если я делаю обычный Html.BeginForm то в случае если я в это поле не ввиду @ то из за этой валидации даже не отправляется форма а если всё хорошо то отправляется. А ajax запросу на это пофигу, он отправляет в любом случае. И ни каких сообщений о валидациях.

Comment: @AK заметил ещё кое что. Можно если это делать ajax запросом результат выполнения запроса(а он то как раз с результатами валидации) запихнуть в `$(document)[0].documentElement.innerHTML = результат запроса` И тогда перепишется html всей страницы и выведутся все ошибки возникшие при валидации.

Comment: @AK но есть ещё 1 вариант. Случайно его заметил. Валидация так скажем на лету. То есть для того что бы так получилось необходимо подключить `@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")` И сделать ajax запрос не с помощью jquery а с помощью хелпера, так скажем обернуть всю разметку в `AJAX.BEGINFORM` и тогда стоит мне например ввести обязательное поле, а потом стереть его, тогда вылезет сообщение что это поле обязательно.

Comment: @AK а у поля `input` с типом `email` есть своя валидация. Я привёл пример на скриншоте в вопросе. С восклицательным знаком. Но при валидации на лету. Вылазиет другое сообщение. Которое я не пойму откуда идёт. Приведу в конце вопроса скриншот с этим сообщением. Но то сообщение которые вылазило на скриншоте где с восклицательным знаком храниться тоже в свойстве validationMessage. Вот мне хотелось юы добиться того что бы при валидации на лету вылазило именно сообщение с русской текстовкой и восклицательным знаком. Как теперь уже на предпоследнем скриншоте.

Comment: @AK надеюсь я всё доходчиво объяснил, как сможете отпишите пожалуйста если знаете как помочь. Если что то не понятно я объясню, могу в чате объяснить.

Comment: Кстати, да, может быть правильно так как вы говорите: я-то привык в core либо полноценно работать без ajax, либо сразу на фронте, особо не пользуясь @Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: @AK добавил скриншот как сейчас работает на "лету".

Comment: Нет, я не особо много писал подобного кода, поэтому методом пристального взгляда вряд ли подскажу что-то путное, думаю проще вам самому с этим вопросом разобраться.

Comment: Всё обёрнуто в ajax.beginform и как только ввёл что то в email и убрал фокус с поля, вылазиет англоязычное сообщение. Но я хочу что бы оно вылезло так как было при отправке формы.

Comment: @AK понял, спасибо за подсказки. Ну я так понял есть несколько вариантов валидировать на клиенте. Либо собрать на сервере все ключи ошибок из состояния модели. Либо записать результат ajax запроса в document на прямую, то есть заменить весь html код страницы. Либо сделать как последний вариант. Валидация на лету.

Comment: @AK взгляните пожалуйста, мне кое что удалось добиться в этом плане, вот ещё вопрос поднял, может что подскажите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929078/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-ajax