# Валидация формы с помощью jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Необходимо валидировать форму. У меня это получилось с помощью `Ajax.Beginform`

View:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.Client

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .form-signin {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 330px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .input-group-text {
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    }

    .form-control {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
</style>

@Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Registration", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Success" }))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CName, "Имя")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите имя" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "Отчество")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CPatronymic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPatr", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите отчество" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Login, "Логин")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Login, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtLogin", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите логин" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Password, "Пароль")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(i => i.Password, new { @id = "txtPass", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите пароль" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Email, "E-Mail")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMail", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите e-mail", @type = "email" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Добавить" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Success(result) {
        $(location).attr('href', result.URL);
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(Client client)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                /*unitOfWork.Clients.Create(client);
                unitOfWork.Save();*/
                var url = new { URL = Url.Content("/Authorization/Index") + "#success" };
                return Json(url);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

И всё работает идеально. Поля выдают сообщения сразу же после ввода данных как и должно быть. И в результате выполнения запроса программу перенаправляет на другую страницу.
Но мне захотелось сделать то же самое с помощью jquery.
Нагуглил вот такой вот вариант.
View:

```
@model AutoStore.Domain.Core.Client

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .form-signin {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 330px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .input-group-text {
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    }

    .form-control {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
</style>

@Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index")

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CSurname, "Фамилия")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtSurname", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите фамилию" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CName, "Имя")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите имя" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "Отчество")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CPatronymic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtPatr", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите отчество" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CPatronymic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Login, "Логин")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Login, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtLogin", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите логин" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Password, "Пароль")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(i => i.Password, new { @id = "txtPass", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите пароль" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Email, "E-Mail")
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtMail", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите e-mail", @type = "email" } })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Добавить" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Authorization/Registration",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $(location).attr('href', result.URL);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

В контроллере всё то же самое.
И всё так же работает, но почему то в отладке клиента я заметил что в success не заходит, решил проверить отладку на сервере и написал `Request.IsAjaxRequest`, результатом было `false` и в итоге выполнения запроса мне просто выдало страницу с текстом адрес:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? Как сделать что бы результат был такой же как и при использовании хелпера?

Comment: У меня есть такое ощущение что из за того что я после запроса не написал `return false` у меня вместо ajax запроса выполняется обычный, но я пробовал и с `return false` результат тот же самый.

Comment: Почему то ajax запрос вообще не выполняется. А вот если вынести его в отдельную функцию и там всё таки использовать `return false` тогда всё работает прекрасно и даже `$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {` не нужно. Хотя я нашёл этот код на стеке и так же в других местах в интернете, в таком виде ajax запрос не в какую работать не хочет. Что в моём коде может быть не так?