# NUnit тесты для WebApi приложения net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, nunit

Я недавно начал программировать на net. У меня следующий вопрос: у меня есть web приложение с базой данных, написаны уровень данных и уровень бизнес логики, как написать nunit тесты для уровня бизнес логики, нашел в интернете что можно использовать moq(mock), но совершенно не понимаю как. Обращение к базе данных происходит через DBContext. Ссылка на проект:(https://github.com/Aleksandr34nov/WebApiApp), кое-что добавлю сюда. Вот попробовал написать тест:

```
namespace BuissnessLayerTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class SongTests
    {
        private static DbContextOptions<ASContext> options;
        private static ASContext context = new ASContext(options);
        private static EFSongsRepository _songRep = new EFSongsRepository(new SongDataAccess(context));
        [Test]
        public void GetItemByIdTest()
        {
            Song song = new Song();
            song.SongTitle = "In The End";
            song.AlbumId = -1;
            int id = _songRep.AddItem(song);
            Song? testSong = _songRep.GetItemById(id);
            _songRep.DeleteItem(song);
            if (song.Equals(testSong))
            {
                Assert.Pass();
            }else 
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Получил ошибку:**
[image: Ошибка]

Не до конца понимаю как это все работает, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать тесты.
**Вот структура проекта:**

[image: Структура проекта]

**Это сам проект:**
Сущность Song:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Domain
    {
        public class Song
        {
            public int SongId { get; set; }
            public string SongTitle { get; set; }
            public int AlbumId { get; set; }
            public Album Album { get; set; }
            public Song() { }
        }
    }
```

Сущность Album:

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public List<Song> SongList { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        public Album() { }
    }
}
```

**Это context:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Domain;

namespace DataLayer
{
    public class ASContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }

        public ASContext(DbContextOptions<ASContext> options) : base(options) { }
    }

    public class EFDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ASContext>
    {
        public ASContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ASContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AlbumsSongsDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataLayer"));

            return new ASContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Могу порекомендовать посмотреть мой проект с тестами на всех уровнях приложения: https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend/tree/master/src возможно, что-нибудь будет понятнее.

Comment: @AK Мое задание по сути звучит так: "Написать слой бизнес-логики приложения, покрыть его тестами (NUnit, FluentAssertions, Moq)" Извиняюсь за картинки(исправлено).

Comment: Приведите код классов EFSongRepository и ISongRepository

Comment: А, я догадался как найти (у вас опечатка в адресе репозитория) ваш проект на гитхабе. Ну, в принципе похоже на то, что я когда-то делал архитектуры на репозиториях: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/766614/213987

Comment: Это может означать что угодно и лучше уточнить у того, кто хотел это сделать, но в принципе, есть следующие направления. Во-первых, вы можете сделать на реальной базе (в моём проекте показаны такие типы тестов), они по факту уже интеграционные, т.к. зависят от реальной базы (и я не стал брать sqlite, а взял честный SQL Server). Во-вторых, вы можете создать поверх Repository отдельные Service'ы которые будут принимать на конструктор Repository и тогда вы сможете замокать репозитории в тестах, создав в тестовом проекте отдельные реализации на IList. И вот тут по факту мокать, мокать и ещё раз м

Comment: @AK Насколько я понял мне нужно протестировать операции из уровня бизнес логики по типу: GetItemById(), GetAllItems(), DeleteItem(). Они у меня написаны в слое бизнес логики, который соединен с уровнем данных и общается с ним через DBContext, мне говорили что нужно "подложить" данные в тестах и протестировать, я не очень понял как "подложить" если методы из слоя общаются с базой через DBContext? Я попытался написать, но не получилось ничего. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: @AK А есть примеры с сервисами? А то я вообще с этим не работал

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое для вас слой бизнес-логики. Ваш проект с бизнес-логикой содержит по факту два проекта: один из них - это определения интерфейсов и это либо делают частью домена, доменной логики, либо в бизнес-логику. Второй проект - это РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ (ОДНА ИЗ реализаций) интерфейсов с БД, исключительно на базе EF (и можно реализовать на чистом Sql, ado.net без EF)

Comment: @AK а на реальной базе в Вашем проекте тесты это тут: Wally.Application.Tests?

Comment: Ну вот например: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.2.php Здесь IOrder - это по факту IOrderService.

Comment: У меня в Wally есть проект Domain и проект Domain.Tests - тесты домена, аналогично Application.Tests - это тесты для слоя Application и так для всех слоёв. Там просто архитектура не на базе репозиториев, а на базе CQRS, хотя в целом подход аналогичный. Тесты для реальной базы - да, там где вы указали.