# Как тестировать методы для работы с бд с помощью generic репозитория?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nunit, moq

[Я разрабатываю web приложения, в котором есть слой бизнес логики и слой уровня данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1267709/213987).
В своем приложении я использую entity-framework для работы с БД.
Необходимо протестировать(nunit тесты) методы работы с БД. Структура на базе репозиториев.
Я слышал что для тестирования методов для работы с БД можно создать generic репозиторий public interface IRepository where T: class { } и для тестирования подсовывать fake репозиторий с тестовыми данными.
Как это делается? Может есть какие-нибудь примеры?
Мой проект на всякий случай: https://github.com/Aleksandr34nov/WebApp/
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Если вы используете репозиторий, то забудьте про его внутреннюю реализацию. У вас есть интерфейс: `IRepositroy` - всё, его и используйте в тестах. А что внутри - Entity Framework, NHibernate, Dapper, ADO.NET - не важно.

Comment: Читайте книгу The Art of Unit Testing - Искусство автономного тестирования, 2-е издание.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я немного не понял, как мне получить данные для тестирования. У меня по сути взаимодействие с базой данных происходит с помощью DBContext. Как мне тестировать эти методы, которые используют DBContext для доступа к бд?

Comment: Забудьте про DbContext, забудьте про Entity Framework! У вас есть только репозиторий - вот его методы и используйте. Именно его методы будете мокать. То есть не будет работы с реальной БД. Будут фейковые данные.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Хорошо, мне как раз и нужно подкладывать фейковые данные, но есть какой-нибудь пример похожий на мое задание или сайт, где про это рассказывается чтобы понять как это сделать? А то я новичок и не очень хорошо понимаю как это работает и как это написать. То есть как подкладывать фейковые данные и как мокать методы?